# Can't log in to Azure: Error: retrieving environments from Azure MetaData service via Terraform plan

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am facing issues from azure metadata service when I am trying to run my terraform plan.
Things I tried.

- removing ~/.azure folder , re-tried `az login` from browser.
- removed ~/.Identity folder as well , but still the same.
- Also added client_id , client_secret , etc from provider block but no luck.

```
Error: retrieving environments from Azure MetaData service: Get "https:///metadata/endpoints?api-version=2019-05-01": http: no Host in request URL

  on main.tf line 1, in provider "azurerm":
   1: provider "azurerm" {
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I tried already to check if this was raised before but no luck.

Comment: @snakechamberb sorry but just I saw you edit the subject and removed terraform part - That was indeed my ,main point. when I am using terraform this `az login` is broken.

Comment: Could you share the part of your terraform configuration where you declare `azurerm` provider? Also, it might help if you add to the question description terraform version, azurerm provider version, how you configure terraform (environment-variables, terraform properties, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by doing 2 things mentioned below.

- remove the ~/.azure and ~/.Identitiy folder from local.
- export ARM_MSI_ENDPOINT=false

Once you do that you should now be able to access the metadata API again for authentication to azure.

Explanation of MSI flag is here [terraform provider MSI use](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/index.html#msi_endpoint)

I wanted to use service principal to authenticate and somehow I got this enabled in provider.